# sudo apt-get remove [software package] removes [software package] but installs something else as well?

Tags: 11.10, apt, purge

I am using **Xubuntu 11.10** Oneric on an old ThinkPad.

Often, when I run `sudo apt-get purge/remove [software package]`, the requested software package, say, **`gnome-shell`, is removed and replaced with what appears to be `ubuntu-desktop`** and all it's dependencies. I didn't read that it was installing anything so I just continued.

The same thing happened when I removed `chromium-browser`, only to be replaced with epiphany.

The terminal session is here (with some parts removed due to body restrictions), and more evidence of this said bug also appears when I try to remove the wrongly installed `unity` package:

```
marco@ThinkPad:~$ sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell
**(parts removed)**
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 epiphany-browser-data libseed-gtk3-0 gnome-js-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt bamfdaemon banshee
  banshee-extension-soundmenu brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common cli-common
  compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default
  compiz-plugins-main-default compizconfig-backend-gconf dvd+rw-tools geoclue
  geoclue-ubuntu-geoip growisofs indicator-appmenu indicator-datetime
  indicator-power indicator-session libbamf3-0 libboost-serialization1.46.1
  libbrasero-media3-1 libcompizconfig0 libdbus-glib1.0-cil libdbus1.0-cil
  libdbusmenu-qt2 libdecoration0 libgconf2.0-cil libgdata1.7-cil libgdiplus
  libgeoclue0 libgkeyfile1.0-cil libglew1.5 libglewmx1.5 libglib2.0-bin
  libglib2.0-cil libgmime-2.4-2 libgtk-sharp-beans-cil libgtk2.0-cil
  libgudev1.0-cil libmono-addins0.2-cil libmono-cairo4.0-cil
  libmono-corlib4.0-cil libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil libmono-i18n4.0-cil
  libmono-posix4.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil
  libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-core4.0-cil
  libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil
  libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libmono-zeroconf1.0-cil
  libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libnotify0.4-cil libnux-1.0-0
  libnux-1.0-common libprotobuf7 libquvi0 libtaglib2.0-cil libtotem-plparser17
  libunity-core-4.0-4 libunity-misc4 media-player-info mono-4.0-gac mono-gac
  mono-runtime nux-tools unity unity-asset-pool unity-common
  unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music
  unity-scope-musicstores unity-services wodim zeitgeist-extension-fts
Suggested packages:
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
  banshee-extension-ubuntuonemusicstore banshee-dbg vcdimager libdvdcss2
  dvdauthor readom compizconfig-settings-manager gnome-themes cdrskin
  gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 cdrdao monodoc-gtk2.0-manual glew-utils1.5
  libmono-i18n4.0-all cdrkit-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED
  gnome-shell*
The following NEW packages will be installed
  appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt bamfdaemon banshee
  banshee-extension-soundmenu brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common cli-common
  compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default
  compiz-plugins-main-default compizconfig-backend-gconf dvd+rw-tools geoclue
  geoclue-ubuntu-geoip growisofs indicator-appmenu indicator-datetime
  indicator-power indicator-session libbamf3-0 libboost-serialization1.46.1
  libbrasero-media3-1 libcompizconfig0 libdbus-glib1.0-cil libdbus1.0-cil
  libdbusmenu-qt2 libdecoration0 libgconf2.0-cil libgdata1.7-cil libgdiplus
  libgeoclue0 libgkeyfile1.0-cil libglew1.5 libglewmx1.5 libglib2.0-bin
  libglib2.0-cil libgmime-2.4-2 libgtk-sharp-beans-cil libgtk2.0-cil
  libgudev1.0-cil libmono-addins0.2-cil libmono-cairo4.0-cil
  libmono-corlib4.0-cil libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil libmono-i18n4.0-cil
  libmono-posix4.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil
  libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-core4.0-cil
  libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil
  libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libmono-zeroconf1.0-cil
  libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libnotify0.4-cil libnux-1.0-0
  libnux-1.0-common libprotobuf7 libquvi0 libtaglib2.0-cil libtotem-plparser17
  libunity-core-4.0-4 libunity-misc4 media-player-info mono-4.0-gac mono-gac
  mono-runtime nux-tools unity unity-asset-pool unity-common
  unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music
  unity-scope-musicstores unity-services wodim zeitgeist-extension-fts
0 upgraded, 87 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 16.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 62.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
**(parts removed)**
Fetched 16.9 MB in 3min 48s (74.0 kB/s)                                        
Extract templates from packages: 100%
Selecting previously deselected package bamfdaemon.
(Reading database ... 216368 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking bamfdaemon (from .../bamfdaemon_0.2.104-0ubuntu1.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libbamf3-0.
Unpacking libbamf3-0 (from .../libbamf3-0_0.2.104-0ubuntu1.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libglew1.5.
Unpacking libglew1.5 (from .../libglew1.5_1.5.7.is.1.5.2-1ubuntu4_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libnux-1.0-common.
Unpacking libnux-1.0-common (from .../libnux-1.0-common_1.16.0-0ubuntu1.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libglewmx1.5.
Unpacking libglewmx1.5 (from .../libglewmx1.5_1.5.7.is.1.5.2-1ubuntu4_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libnux-1.0-0.
Unpacking libnux-1.0-0 (from .../libnux-1.0-0_1.16.0-0ubuntu1.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package unity-services.
Unpacking unity-services (from .../unity-services_4.28.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libunity-core-4.0-4.
Unpacking libunity-core-4.0-4 (from .../libunity-core-4.0-4_4.28.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libunity-misc4.
Unpacking libunity-misc4 (from .../libunity-misc4_4.0.4-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package unity-common.
Unpacking unity-common (from .../unity-common_4.28.0-0ubuntu2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package compiz-core.
Unpacking compiz-core (from .../compiz-core_1%3a0.9.6+bzr20110929-0ubuntu6.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libdecoration0.
Unpacking libdecoration0 (from .../libdecoration0_1%3a0.9.6+bzr20110929-0ubuntu6.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package compiz-plugins-default.
Unpacking compiz-plugins-default (from .../compiz-plugins-default_1%3a0.9.6+bzr20110929-0ubuntu6.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libprotobuf7.
Unpacking libprotobuf7 (from .../libprotobuf7_2.4.0a-2ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libcompizconfig0.
Unpacking libcompizconfig0 (from .../libcompizconfig0_0.9.5.94-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package compizconfig-backend-gconf.
Unpacking compizconfig-backend-gconf (from .../compizconfig-backend-gconf_0.9.5.92-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package compiz-gnome.
Unpacking compiz-gnome (from .../compiz-gnome_1%3a0.9.6+bzr20110929-0ubuntu6.1_i386.deb) ...
^[[A^[[ASelecting previously deselected package libboost-serialization1.46.1.
Unpacking libboost-serialization1.46.1 (from .../libboost-serialization1.46.1_1.46.1-5ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package compiz-plugins-main-default.
Unpacking compiz-plugins-main-default (from .../compiz-plugins-main-default_1%3a0.9.6-0ubuntu4.2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package compiz.
Unpacking compiz (from .../compiz_1%3a0.9.6+bzr20110929-0ubuntu6.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libglib2.0-bin.
Unpacking libglib2.0-bin (from .../libglib2.0-bin_2.30.0-0ubuntu4_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package nux-tools.
Unpacking nux-tools (from .../nux-tools_1.16.0-0ubuntu1.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package unity-asset-pool.
Unpacking unity-asset-pool (from .../unity-asset-pool_0.8.22-0ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package unity.
Unpacking unity (from .../unity_4.28.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0 ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Setting up bamfdaemon (0.2.104-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Setting up libbamf3-0 (0.2.104-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libglew1.5 (1.5.7.is.1.5.2-1ubuntu4) ...
Setting up libnux-1.0-common (1.16.0-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libglewmx1.5 (1.5.7.is.1.5.2-1ubuntu4) ...
Setting up libnux-1.0-0 (1.16.0-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up unity-services (4.28.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libunity-core-4.0-4 (4.28.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libunity-misc4 (4.0.4-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up unity-common (4.28.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up compiz-core (1:0.9.6+bzr20110929-0ubuntu6.1) ...
Setting up libdecoration0 (1:0.9.6+bzr20110929-0ubuntu6.1) ...
Setting up compiz-plugins-default (1:0.9.6+bzr20110929-0ubuntu6.1) ...
Setting up libprotobuf7 (2.4.0a-2ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libcompizconfig0 (0.9.5.94-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up compizconfig-backend-gconf (0.9.5.92-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up compiz-gnome (1:0.9.6+bzr20110929-0ubuntu6.1) ...
Setting up libboost-serialization1.46.1 (1.46.1-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up compiz-plugins-main-default (1:0.9.6-0ubuntu4.2) ...
Setting up compiz (1:0.9.6+bzr20110929-0ubuntu6.1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-bin (2.30.0-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up nux-tools (1.16.0-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up unity-asset-pool (0.8.22-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up unity (4.28.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
(Reading database ... 216937 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gnome-shell ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0 ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Selecting previously deselected package libdbusmenu-qt2.
(Reading database ... 216915 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libdbusmenu-qt2 (from .../libdbusmenu-qt2_0.9.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmtp-common.
Unpacking libmtp-common (from .../libmtp-common_1.1.0-3ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmtp9.
Unpacking libmtp9 (from .../libmtp9_1.1.0-3ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package appmenu-gtk.
Unpacking appmenu-gtk (from .../appmenu-gtk_0.3.0-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package appmenu-gtk3.
Unpacking appmenu-gtk3 (from .../appmenu-gtk3_0.3.0-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package appmenu-qt.
Unpacking appmenu-qt (from .../appmenu-qt_0.2.2-0ubuntu1.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-corlib4.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-corlib4.0-cil (from .../libmono-corlib4.0-cil_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-system-xml4.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (from .../libmono-system-xml4.0-cil_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-system-security4.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-system-security4.0-cil (from .../libmono-system-security4.0-cil_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil (from .../libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-system4.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-system4.0-cil (from .../libmono-system4.0-cil_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-security4.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-security4.0-cil (from .../libmono-security4.0-cil_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mono-4.0-gac.
Unpacking mono-4.0-gac (from .../mono-4.0-gac_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mono-gac.
Unpacking mono-gac (from .../mono-gac_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mono-runtime.
Unpacking mono-runtime (from .../mono-runtime_2.10.5-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package cli-common.
Unpacking cli-common (from .../cli-common_0.8~xamarin1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-posix4.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-posix4.0-cil (from .../libmono-posix4.0-cil_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-system-core4.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-system-core4.0-cil (from .../libmono-system-core4.0-cil_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libdbus1.0-cil.
Unpacking libdbus1.0-cil (from .../libdbus1.0-cil_0.7.0-4_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libdbus-glib1.0-cil.
Unpacking libdbus-glib1.0-cil (from .../libdbus-glib1.0-cil_0.5.0-3build1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libglib2.0-cil.
Unpacking libglib2.0-cil (from .../libglib2.0-cil_2.12.10-2ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libgconf2.0-cil.
Unpacking libgconf2.0-cil (from .../libgconf2.0-cil_2.24.2-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libgdata1.7-cil.
Unpacking libgdata1.7-cil (from .../libgdata1.7-cil_1.7.0.1-1build1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libgkeyfile1.0-cil.
Unpacking libgkeyfile1.0-cil (from .../libgkeyfile1.0-cil_0.1-2ubuntu2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-cairo4.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-cairo4.0-cil (from .../libmono-cairo4.0-cil_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libgdiplus.
Unpacking libgdiplus (from .../libgdiplus_2.10-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil (from .../libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libgtk2.0-cil.
Unpacking libgtk2.0-cil (from .../libgtk2.0-cil_2.12.10-2ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libgtk-sharp-beans-cil.
Unpacking libgtk-sharp-beans-cil (from .../libgtk-sharp-beans-cil_2.14.1-2build2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libgudev1.0-cil.
Unpacking libgudev1.0-cil (from .../libgudev1.0-cil_0.1-2build1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil.
Unpacking libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil (from .../libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-addins0.2-cil.
Unpacking libmono-addins0.2-cil (from .../libmono-addins0.2-cil_0.6.1-2ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-zeroconf1.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-zeroconf1.0-cil (from .../libmono-zeroconf1.0-cil_0.9.0-3~ubuntu0.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libnotify0.4-cil.
Unpacking libnotify0.4-cil (from .../libnotify0.4-cil_0.4.0~r3032-4~ubuntu0.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libtaglib2.0-cil.
Unpacking libtaglib2.0-cil (from .../libtaglib2.0-cil_2.0.3.7+dfsg-1build1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package banshee.
Unpacking banshee (from .../banshee_2.2.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package banshee-extension-soundmenu.
Unpacking banshee-extension-soundmenu (from .../banshee-extension-soundmenu_2.2.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libgmime-2.4-2.
Unpacking libgmime-2.4-2 (from .../libgmime-2.4-2_2.4.26-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libquvi0.
Unpacking libquvi0 (from .../libquvi0_0.2.15-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libtotem-plparser17.
Unpacking libtotem-plparser17 (from .../libtotem-plparser17_2.32.6-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package growisofs.
Unpacking growisofs (from .../growisofs_7.1-10_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package dvd+rw-tools.
Unpacking dvd+rw-tools (from .../dvd+rw-tools_7.1-10_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package brasero-common.
Unpacking brasero-common (from .../brasero-common_3.2.0-0ubuntu1.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libbrasero-media3-1.
Unpacking libbrasero-media3-1 (from .../libbrasero-media3-1_3.2.0-0ubuntu1.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package brasero.
Unpacking brasero (from .../brasero_3.2.0-0ubuntu1.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package wodim.
Unpacking wodim (from .../wodim_9%3a1.1.11-1ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package brasero-cdrkit.
Unpacking brasero-cdrkit (from .../brasero-cdrkit_3.2.0-0ubuntu1.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libgeoclue0.
Unpacking libgeoclue0 (from .../libgeoclue0_0.12.0-1ubuntu10_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package geoclue.
Unpacking geoclue (from .../geoclue_0.12.0-1ubuntu10_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package geoclue-ubuntu-geoip.
Unpacking geoclue-ubuntu-geoip (from .../geoclue-ubuntu-geoip_0.0.2-0ubuntu6_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package indicator-appmenu.
Unpacking indicator-appmenu (from .../indicator-appmenu_0.3.1-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package indicator-datetime.
Unpacking indicator-datetime (from .../indicator-datetime_0.3.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package indicator-power.
Unpacking indicator-power (from .../indicator-power_0.9-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package indicator-session.
Unpacking indicator-session (from .../indicator-session_0.3.7.1-0ubuntu1.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-i18n4.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-i18n4.0-cil (from .../libmono-i18n4.0-cil_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil (from .../libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil_2.10.5-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libmtp-runtime.
Unpacking libmtp-runtime (from .../libmtp-runtime_1.1.0-3ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package media-player-info.
Unpacking media-player-info (from .../media-player-info_15-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package zeitgeist-extension-fts.
Unpacking zeitgeist-extension-fts (from .../zeitgeist-extension-fts_0.0.13-0ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package unity-lens-applications.
Unpacking unity-lens-applications (from .../unity-lens-applications_0.4.12-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package unity-lens-files.
Unpacking unity-lens-files (from .../unity-lens-files_0.6.12-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package unity-lens-music.
Unpacking unity-lens-music (from .../unity-lens-music_0.2.6-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package unity-scope-musicstores.
Unpacking unity-scope-musicstores (from .../unity-scope-musicstores_0.2.6-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Processing triggers for menu ...
Processing triggers for doc-base ...
Processing 1 added doc-base file...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for gconf2 ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0 ...
Setting up libdbusmenu-qt2 (0.9.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libmtp-common (1.1.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libmtp9 (1.1.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up appmenu-gtk (0.3.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up appmenu-gtk3 (0.3.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up appmenu-qt (0.2.2-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up cli-common (0.8~xamarin1) ...
Setting up libgdiplus (2.10-2) ...
Setting up libgmime-2.4-2 (2.4.26-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libquvi0 (0.2.15-1) ...
Setting up libtotem-plparser17 (2.32.6-1) ...
Setting up growisofs (7.1-10) ...
Setting up dvd+rw-tools (7.1-10) ...
Setting up brasero-common (3.2.0-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libbrasero-media3-1 (3.2.0-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up brasero (3.2.0-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up wodim (9:1.1.11-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up brasero-cdrkit (3.2.0-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libgeoclue0 (0.12.0-1ubuntu10) ...
Setting up geoclue (0.12.0-1ubuntu10) ...
Setting up geoclue-ubuntu-geoip (0.0.2-0ubuntu6) ...
Setting up indicator-appmenu (0.3.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up indicator-datetime (0.3.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up indicator-power (0.9-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up indicator-session (0.3.7.1-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libmtp-runtime (1.1.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up media-player-info (15-1) ...
Setting up zeitgeist-extension-fts (0.0.13-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up unity-lens-applications (0.4.12-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up unity-lens-files (0.6.12-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up unity-lens-music (0.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up unity-scope-musicstores (0.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libmono-corlib4.0-cil (2.10.5-1) ...
Setting up libmono-cairo4.0-cil (2.10.5-1) ...
Setting up libtaglib2.0-cil (2.0.3.7+dfsg-1build1) ...
* Installing 2 assemblies from libtaglib2.0-cil into Mono
Setting up libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (2.10.5-1) ...
Setting up libmono-security4.0-cil (2.10.5-1) ...
Setting up mono-4.0-gac (2.10.5-1) ...
Setting up mono-gac (2.10.5-1) ...
* Installing 1 assembly from libdbus1.0-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libdbus-glib1.0-cil into Mono
* Installing 6 assemblies from libgconf2.0-cil into Mono
* Installing 14 assemblies from libgdata1.7-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libgkeyfile1.0-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libglib2.0-cil into Mono
* Installing 5 assemblies from libgtk2.0-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libgudev1.0-cil into Mono
* Installing 15 assemblies from libmono-addins0.2-cil into Mono
* Installing 5 assemblies from libmono-zeroconf1.0-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libnotify0.4-cil into Mono
* Installing 2 assemblies from libtaglib2.0-cil into Mono
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/gacutil to provide /usr/bin/cli-gacutil (global-assembly-cache-tool) in auto mode.
Setting up mono-runtime (2.10.5-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/mono to provide /usr/bin/cli (cli) in auto mode.
Setting up libmono-i18n4.0-cil (2.10.5-1) ...
Setting up libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil (2.10.5-1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-security4.0-cil (2.10.5-1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil (2.10.5-1) ...
Setting up libmono-system4.0-cil (2.10.5-1) ...
Setting up libmono-posix4.0-cil (2.10.5-1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-core4.0-cil (2.10.5-1) ...
Setting up libdbus1.0-cil (0.7.0-4) ...
* Installing 1 assembly from libdbus1.0-cil into Mono
Setting up libdbus-glib1.0-cil (0.5.0-3build1) ...
* Installing 1 assembly from libdbus-glib1.0-cil into Mono
Setting up libglib2.0-cil (2.12.10-2ubuntu1) ...
* Installing 1 assembly from libglib2.0-cil into Mono
Setting up libgconf2.0-cil (2.24.2-1) ...
* Installing 6 assemblies from libgconf2.0-cil into Mono
Setting up libgdata1.7-cil (1.7.0.1-1build1) ...
* Installing 14 assemblies from libgdata1.7-cil into Mono
Setting up libgkeyfile1.0-cil (0.1-2ubuntu2) ...
* Installing 1 assembly from libgkeyfile1.0-cil into Mono
Setting up libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil (2.10.5-1) ...
Setting up libgtk2.0-cil (2.12.10-2ubuntu1) ...
* Installing 5 assemblies from libgtk2.0-cil into Mono
Setting up libgtk-sharp-beans-cil (2.14.1-2build2) ...
Setting up libgudev1.0-cil (0.1-2build1) ...
* Installing 1 assembly from libgudev1.0-cil into Mono
Setting up libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil (2.10.5-1) ...
Setting up libmono-addins0.2-cil (0.6.1-2ubuntu1) ...
* Installing 15 assemblies from libmono-addins0.2-cil into Mono
Setting up libmono-zeroconf1.0-cil (0.9.0-3~ubuntu0.1) ...
* Installing 5 assemblies from libmono-zeroconf1.0-cil into Mono
Setting up libnotify0.4-cil (0.4.0~r3032-4~ubuntu0.1) ...
* Installing 1 assembly from libnotify0.4-cil into Mono
Setting up banshee (2.2.1-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up banshee-extension-soundmenu (2.2.1-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for menu ...
marco@ThinkPad:~$ sudo apt-get purge unity
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-folks-0.6 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 mutter-common gir1.2-json-1.0 libcaribou0 gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0
  gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 epiphany-browser-data gir1.2-gkbd-3.0
  gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 libseed-gtk3-0 caribou libfolks25 libmutter0 gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gjs
  gir1.2-caribou-1.0 libtelepathy-logger2 gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 gnome-js-common cups-pk-helper
  libatspi2.0-0 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 python-pyatspi2 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 libmozjs185-1.0
  gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 gir1.2-gee-1.0 libgjs0c gnome-shell-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdconf-dbus-1-0 libdconf-qt0 libqtbamf1 libqtdee2 libqtgconf1 libunity-2d-private0 unity-2d
  unity-2d-launcher unity-2d-panel unity-2d-places unity-2d-spread
The following packages will be REMOVED
  unity*
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libdconf-dbus-1-0 libdconf-qt0 libqtbamf1 libqtdee2 libqtgconf1 libunity-2d-private0 unity-2d
  unity-2d-launcher unity-2d-panel unity-2d-places unity-2d-spread
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,046 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,221 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
marco@ThinkPad:~$ sudo apt-get remove unity
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-folks-0.6 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 mutter-common gir1.2-json-1.0 libcaribou0 gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0
  gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 epiphany-browser-data gir1.2-gkbd-3.0
  gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 libseed-gtk3-0 caribou libfolks25 libmutter0 gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gjs
  gir1.2-caribou-1.0 libtelepathy-logger2 gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 gnome-js-common cups-pk-helper
  libatspi2.0-0 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 python-pyatspi2 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 libmozjs185-1.0
  gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 gir1.2-gee-1.0 libgjs0c gnome-shell-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdconf-dbus-1-0 libdconf-qt0 libqtbamf1 libqtdee2 libqtgconf1 libunity-2d-private0 unity-2d
  unity-2d-launcher unity-2d-panel unity-2d-places unity-2d-spread
The following packages will be REMOVED
  unity
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libdconf-dbus-1-0 libdconf-qt0 libqtbamf1 libqtdee2 libqtgconf1 libunity-2d-private0 unity-2d
  unity-2d-launcher unity-2d-panel unity-2d-places unity-2d-spread
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,046 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,221 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
marco@ThinkPad ~$
```

***What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. If you remove a system critical package, it must be replaced with something that can take it's place. If, on the other hand, the package being removed is not system critical, yes, it is a bug and should be reported to launchpad. A browser is required for correct operation. If you remove Firefox and replace it with something else, then when removing something else, it is replaced by a usable browser.

If any -desktop package is installed, when installing and removing the components needed for that package, it insures enough packages remain for your desktop to actually work.

Comment: But then, how do I remove all these unneeded packages that come up after removing `gnome-shell`, since all I want is Xubuntu and XFCE sessions. I removed the '.desktop' files, but I want to rid the system of all the unnecessary packages I just installed.